# Exception running application application

Tags: javafx, fxml

This is my fx class

```
package application;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

          Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("as1.fxml"));


        primaryStage.setTitle("Abdul-Rahim University");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 500));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

and this is as1.fxml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SeparatorMenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.GaussianBlur?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.MotionBlur?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<VBox prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="640.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="abd">
  <children>
    <MenuBar VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
      <menus>
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
          <items>
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="New" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Open…" />
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Open Recent" />
            <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save As…" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Revert" />
            <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Preferences…" />
            <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Quit" />
          </items>
        </Menu>
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
          <items>
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Undo" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Redo" />
            <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Cut" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Copy" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Paste" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
            <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Select All" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Unselect All" />
          </items>
        </Menu>
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
          <items>
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About MyHelloApp" />
          </items>
        </Menu>
      </menus>
    </MenuBar>
    <AnchorPane fx:id="ar" maxHeight="-1.0" maxWidth="-1.0" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
      <children>
            <BorderPane fx:id="bo" layoutX="69.0" layoutY="32.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
            <HBox fx:id="hb" focusTraversable="true" layoutX="70.0" layoutY="128.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="420.0" spacing="10.0">
               <children>
                  <Button fx:id="st" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="Students" />
                  <Button fx:id="ac" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction2" text="Academics" />
                  <Button fx:id="co" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction3" text="Courses" />
               </children>
               <opaqueInsets>
                  <Insets bottom="11.0" left="11.0" right="11.0" top="10.0" />
               </opaqueInsets>
               <effect>
                  <GaussianBlur radius="1.75" />
               </effect>
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
               </padding>
            </HBox>
            <Label fx:id="l1" contentDisplay="BOTTOM" layoutX="236.0" layoutY="26.0" text="University" textAlignment="CENTER" textOverrun="WORD_ELLIPSIS">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Dubai Regular" size="33.0" />
               </font>
               <effect>
                  <MotionBlur radius="5.5" />
               </effect>
            </Label>
      </children>
    </AnchorPane>
  </children>
</VBox>
```

I have tried to solve it alot and i cant if anyone can help me please solve this problem to me Exception running application applicatio i have tried to solve it alot and i cant if anyone can help me please solve this problem to me Exception running application applicatio

eclipse

```
 Exception in Application start method
 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
     at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
     at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
     at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
 /C:/Users/Abdurrahim/Desktop/mamoun/GUI/bin/application/as1.fxml:18

     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:103)
     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:922)
     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
     at application.Main.start(Main.java:18)
     at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
     at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
     ... 1 more
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: abd
     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:920)
     ... 22 more Exception running application application.Main
```

my controller

```
package application;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;

public class FXMLDocumentController {

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane ar;

    @FXML
    private BorderPane bo;

    @FXML
    private HBox hb;

    @FXML
    private Button st;

    @FXML
    private Button ac;

    @FXML
    private Button co;

    @FXML
    private Label l1;

    @FXML
    void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {

        System.out.println("abd");

    }

    @FXML
    void handleButtonAction2(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("abd");

    }

    @FXML
    void handleButtonAction3(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("abd");

    }

}
```

javafx

Comment: Reposting the same question more than once is not only annoying, but does not help you or anyone else. Please do not do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution: `fx:controller="application.FXMLDocumentController"`